# Format request before send by ClientProxy

Tags: microservices, nestjs

I use microservices and RabbitMQ as a transporter. My microservices communicate with each other, so one of them can send message to another one. I use the following way to send messages:

```
await this.client.send(SOME_COMMAND, obj).toPromise();
```

Now I need to format objects I send in all requests to any microservice in one place. For example add reqId, or serialize Map. Is it possible?

Comment: do you want an `interceptor` ?

Comment: Nope. Interceptor handles income requests and can be used, for example, to format answers. In my case I need to format request which is initied by microservice by itself in any place of code

Comment: I think if you are using `@nestjs/microservices` module then you won't be able to do that as here described https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport#client-proxy

Comment: The neer solution would be creating your custom `clientProxy`

Comment: note that interceptors are not just for request you can do bindings on input/output of methods in `controllers`

Comment: I didn't know, will check it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: you need to pass custom `Serializer` to the `ClientProviderOptions` and you can implement everything there

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Per controller solution. here for simplicity I removed the handler part:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(@Inject('MATH_SERVICE') private client: ClientProxy) {
     let send = client.send.bind(client);
     client.send = function (pattern, payload) {
      
       return send(pattern, { payload, systemWideProp: ""})
    }
  }
  sum() {
    this.client.send(COMMAND, obj)
  }
}
```

**2.** This could be as a `provider` for injecting it on each controller you want using your `rabbitmq` client service:

**custom-client-proxy.ts**

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';

@Injectable()
export class CustomClientProxy {
    constructor(@Inject('MATH_SERVICE') private client: ClientProxy) { }
    send(pattern, payload) {
        // payload and pattern manipulations such as: 
        // payload.say = "Hi";
        // const scopePattern = { cmd: `${pattern.cmd}_dev` };
        return this.client.send(pattern, payload)
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CustomClientProxy } from './custom-client-proxy';

@Module({
  imports: [ClientsModule.register([{
    name: 'MATH_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
      queue: 'math_queue'
    },
  }])],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, CustomClientProxy],
  exports: [CustomClientProxy] // export here for other modules of your app
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.controller.ts**
also any controller you have imported under app's modules

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private client: CustomClientProxy) {}
  sum() {
    this.client.send(COMMAND, obj)
  }

}
```

**3.** When you need to use this functionality for more than one `queue`:

```js
// custom-client-proxy.ts

@Injectable()
export class CustomClientProxy {
    constructor() { }
    send(client: ClientProxy, pattern, payload) {
        // payload and pattern manipulations such as: 
        // payload.say = "Hi";
        // const scopePattern = { cmd: `${pattern.cmd}_dev` };
        return client.send(pattern, payload)
    }
}

// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [ClientsModule.register([{
    name: 'MATH_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
      queue: 'math_queue'
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'MESSAGE_SERVICE',
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: ['amqp://localhost:5672'],
      queue: 'message_queue',
    },
  }])],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService, CustomClientProxy],
  exports: [CustomClientProxy]
})
export class AppModule { }

// app.controller.ts
@Controller()
export class AppController {

  constructor(
    @Inject('MATH_SERVICE') private mathClient: ClientProxy,
    @Inject('MESSAGE_SERVICE') private messageClient: ClientProxy,
    private client: CustomClientProxy) {}

  
  sum(a) {
    return this.client.sendTo(this.mathClient, pattern, payload);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works, but why not create a wrapper class that could be re-used that does the formatting before passing the data on to the `send` method? The class would inject the `ClientProxy` and now anything that injects this wrapper gets the same formatting, without having to reassign the `send` method itself

Comment: @JayMcDoniel This would be the best one, so I am working on that as a new service that can be used everywhere in `nestjs` service

Comment: something like `handlePayload = (payload)  => { // manipulate custom props or any serialization 
return newPayload } `

Comment: and what about token (service name) in your example it is hardcoded.

Comment: let's say I have microservice A and it makes requests to B, C, D. Do I need to write 3 CustomClienProxies, or it is possible to write one but universal for B, C, D clients?

Comment: the third solution gives you the option to use `customProxy` for multiple service usage without creating a new one, but there is the 4th solution that is wrapping each queue module by `customProxy`  while importing them

Comment: Ok, guys, I have spent some time and still can't get solution. Jay, in your case if your class will inject ClientProxy the token will be hardcoded as well. The third solution looks nice, but I already have tons of services and and change send method everywhere is hard. Currently I have implemented something primitive and stupid but it does job: `client['s'] = client.send;
        client.send = function<TResult = any, TInput = any>(pattern: any, data: TInput): Observable<TResult>{
            //serialize here
            return client['s'](pattern, data)
        }`

Comment: @Artem please answer your question with the last solution you had found

Comment: Yeh, it was bad idea, the answer is simple and much more elegant